OpenModelica "linear system solver failed" when using OMPython with ModelicaSystem
I made a model of a cardiovascular system with OpenModelica. The model is very complex so I can't post it all here.
If I run the model from the terminal or using OMCSessionZMQ (like shown below) there are no issues (other than some warnings) and the simulation finishes successfully.
omc = omp.OMCSessionZMQ()
for cmd in cmds: # cmds is an array of "loadFile(file.mo)" strings
         omc.sendExpression(cmd)
omc.sendExpression("simulate(System, stopTime=1000.0)")

And I get this output:
LOG_STDOUT        | warning | The default linear solver fails, the fallback solver with total pivoting is started at time 0.000000. That might raise performance issues, for more information use -lv LOG_LS.
LOG_STDOUT        | warning | The default linear solver fails, the fallback solver with total pivoting is started at time 0.000000. That might raise performance issues, for more information use -lv LOG_LS.
LOG_SUCCESS       | info    | The initialization finished successfully without homotopy method.
LOG_SUCCESS       | info    | The simulation finished successfully.

The issue comes when I use ModelicaSystem to create a model object in order to set the parameters and get the results more easily, using OMPython's API. When I try to simulate the model, the solver fails. Below there is the code fragment with ModelicaSystem and the printed output.
   mod = omp.ModelicaSystem(absolute_path, # to system.mo file
                             'System',
                             ['Modelica']
                             )
    ### SET PARAMETERS
    param_changes = []
    for param_name in parameters.keys():
        param_value = parameters[param_name]
        param_changes.append(f'params.{param_name}={param_value}')
    mod.setParameters(param_changes)

    ### SIMULATE
    mod.setSimulationOptions(["startTime=0.0",
                                f"stopTime={simulation_time}.0",
                                "tolerance=1e-06",
                                "stepSize=0.002"
                              ])
    mod.simulate()

LOG_STDOUT        | warning | The default linear solver fails, the fallback solver with total pivoting is started at time 0.000000. That might raise performance issues, for more information use -lv LOG_LS.
LOG_STDOUT        | warning | The default linear solver fails, the fallback solver with total pivoting is started at time 0.000000. That might raise performance issues, for more information use -lv LOG_LS.
LOG_SUCCESS       | info    | The initialization finished successfully without homotopy method.
LOG_STDOUT        | warning | The default linear solver fails, the fallback solver with total pivoting is started at time 0.000000. That might raise performance issues, for more information use -lv LOG_LS.
LOG_STDOUT        | warning | Error solving linear system of equations (no. 961) at time 0.000000.
LOG_STDOUT        | warning | Solving linear system 961 fails at time 0. For more information use -lv LOG_LS.
LOG_ASSERT        | debug   | Solving linear system 961 failed at time=0.
|                 | |       | For more information please use -lv LOG_LS.
LOG_STDOUT        | info    | model terminate | linear system solver failed. | Simulation terminated at time 0

Why does ModelicaSystem fails and OMCSessionZMQ doesn't? How can I fix this?
I would really like to use the OMPython API to change the parameters and get the results without having to tweak files "by hand".
I thought the issue was with the mod.setSimulationOptions(...) function overriding the default settings, but even without calling it the solver still fails. I think it might have to do with some environmental factors but I wouldn't know where to look.

I am not 100% sure, but your ModelicaSystem example uses a step size of 0.002, stopTime of 1000 = 500 000 steps? The example using simulate only does 500 steps. If you put numberOfIntervals = 500 000 for the first one, does it still fail?

Hi, thank you. Where should "numberOfIntervals" be put? in the simulate call or in the setSimulateOptions call?

If using ModelicaSystem, it should be in setSimulationOptions. If using OMPython directly without ModelicaSystem, it goes in the simulate call.
